# Using Acumatica REST API with Microsoft Flow

Tags: acumatica

Has anyone tried using the Acumatica REST APIs with Microsoft Flow?

I tried it a few weeks ago using Sergey's instructions ([click here](http://asiablog.acumatica.com/2016/12/acumatica-and-microsoft-flow.html)) and it worked fine.

But now I'm getting the following message on the second step.

{
  "message": "You are not logged in."
}

The first step is where I authenticate (just like in Sergey's instructions), then I pass the headers from the first step to the second step (just like in Sergey's instructions), but somehow the second step doesn't think that I'm logged in.

Any ideas?

Here are some screenshots (the only thing I changed for the screenshot is the password):

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOzbG.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDhTg.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4n4I.png

Here are the Headers Outputs from the first call (HTTP):
X-Handled-By
Acumatica-PX.Export/AuthenticationManagerModule
Set-Cookie
ASP.NET_SessionId=0koh1ysshqsfmzr0srib2s5z; path=/; HttpOnly,UserBranch=16; path=/,Locale=Culture=en-US&TimeZone=GMTM0800A; expires=Sat, 18-Nov-2017 17:51:27 GMT; path=/,.ASPXAUTH=880C71F4E1A76C36E7E468337C01BC9E6E4C898E1977BAAAF2A35F7217B1D9132794A9547071508A35A2D4B9132DC4B55E86DD6E9C9B8D46CAECE39D74CC9B44BDD47E7C0D836D22D8F4EEFAF8142A9987418B8003EFF5B340DF735E7F8F36EDE5D25300D887E4DADEB0A80B707D87F6B0D32437; path=/; HttpOnly
Server
Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By
ASP.NET
Date
Wed, 15 Nov 2017 17:51:27 GMT
Content-Length
0

Here are the Headers Inputs from the second call (HTTP 2):
{
  "X-Handled-By": "Acumatica-PX.Export/AuthenticationManagerModule",
  "Set-Cookie": "ASP.NET_SessionId=0koh1ysshqsfmzr0srib2s5z; path=/; HttpOnly,UserBranch=16; path=/,Locale=Culture=en-US&TimeZone=GMTM0800A; expires=Sat, 18-Nov-2017 17:51:27 GMT; path=/,.ASPXAUTH=880C71F4E1A76C36E7E468337C01BC9E6E4C898E1977BAAAF2A35F7217B1D9132794A9547071508A35A2D4B9132DC4B55E86DD6E9C9B8D46CAECE39D74CC9B44BDD47E7C0D836D22D8F4EEFAF8142A9987418B8003EFF5B340DF735E7F8F36EDE5D25300D887E4DADEB0A80B707D87F6B0D32437; path=/; HttpOnly",
  "Server": "Microsoft-IIS/7.5",
  "X-Powered-By": "ASP.NET",
  "Date": "Wed, 15 Nov 2017 17:51:27 GMT",
  "Content-Length": "0"
}

Here are the Headers Outputs from the second call (HTTP 2):
X-Handled-By
Acumatica-PX.Export/AuthenticationManagerModule
Date
Wed, 15 Nov 2017 17:51:27 GMT
Set-Cookie
ASP.NET_SessionId=dklemj2usv2zveyc3acxnhm5; path=/; HttpOnly
Server
Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By
ASP.NET
Content-Length
36
Content-Type
application/json; charset=utf-8

Comment: I should point out that the same method above works in Postman. It just doesn't work in Microsoft Flow.

Comment: I agree with your assessment that the cookies aren't passed between calls in this thread: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Passing-Headers-Between-HTTP-Calls/td-p/69125

Comment: Comparing Auth request header output with Put Customer request header output, it seems the Session ID has changed between the two calls.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just updated the post with the Headers from each step.

Comment: Is pretty clear with the last HTTP 2 headers output that the Session ID is different when it shouldn't be. Unfortunately I don't know how we could fix that because Headers Input looks reasonably well formed.

Comment: I didn't change my Acumatica build so the only thing that could have changed is Microsoft Flow. I wish I had a screenshot of the outputs from when it was working to confirm, but I don't. So, it seems like this isn't an Acumatica issue. I'll lean on the post that you referenced early in the Microsoft Flow forum. Hopefully something comes out of that.

Comment: Can you simply use OAuth 2? Acumatica supports it starting from 2017R2, and it should save you a lot of hassle.

Answer (score 1):

I had one previously and the difference that I see between your and mine is that your login post doesn't have any headers.

Mine had :

Accept                application/json

Content-Type          application/json

Here is a screenshot of my working flow : https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRVny.jpg

**EDIT :**

After playing with this a bit more I have found a way off making this work. though it is using OAuth authentication instead of cookie based authentication.
Here is how :

1. I first created a connected application on the screen of the same name in acumatica

   - Of the following type : Ressource Owner Password Credentials
   - I also created added a shared secret while taking note of its value (it is only showed once).

---

2. I created the first http call in flow using the following information

   - URL : https://"Acumatica ERP instance URL"/identity/connect/token
   - Header : Content type /  application/x-www-form-urlencoded
   - Body : grant_type=password&client_id=Value1&client_secret=Value2&username=Value3&password=Value4&scope=api

Value1 : ID of the connected application created in step 1

Value2 :Value of the shared secret saved from step 1. If lost just remove and add another secret. just be careful no one else is using that secret

Value3 : Username of existing account

Value4 : Password of account specified in value 3

---

3. Create the second HTTP call that will do the web service request

   - URL : https://"Acumatica ERP instance URL"/entity/Default/17.200.001/Case
   - Header : Authorization / bearer substring(substring(string(body('HTTP_2')),indexOf(string(body('HTTP_2')),':'),34),2,32)
   - Body : a normal REST API body for the requested operation

*The Substring is only separated by a space in the header*

---

Here are image representing the 2 HTTP calls
[image: First HTTP call in Flow]
[image: Second HTTP call in Flow]

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot. I tried that, but it doesn't work. Have you run this Flow recently? Mine was working a couple of weeks ago. It's only recently that it stopped working.

Comment: You were right Tim, I have just tried running it again and it failed for the same reason

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Good to know that it's not just me.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for figuring out how to get it to work with OAuth instead of Cookie Based Authentication.

Also, here is an additional post on the subject:
https://www.timrodman.com/connecting-clouds-web-services-summit-2018/